# How are geometry and space related?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

How are geometry and space related?

I am asking in what type of relationship are "space" and "geometry". I can think of the relationship "necessity", but it's a very general relationship.  I can't think of a word to describe the most specific relationship that ties these two concepts together.

> Space and geometry are related by ____.
>
> Space and geometry are in a ____ relationship.

Comment: "How are geometry and space related?" is not a question that can be answered on StackExchange. This is a deep area of controversy in philosophy. You might consider narrowing your question to something like: "What is [insert philosopher here]'s account of the relation between geometry and space?" or "What are some of the main positions one can take with respect to the relation between geometry and space?"

Comment: This is really a question for English SE. I am guessing, "geometry is the science of space" is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Conifold Perhaps, but "geometry is the science of space" is a pretty old-fashioned view of geometry. Hence why I wanted to impart the sense of controversy surrounding this question.

Comment: Geometry is a model of space.

Comment: @transitionsynthesis I agree. But my sense of the OP is that they are looking for phrasing rather than philosophical nuance, which is why we are a wrong site for them.

Comment: See Irving Adler “A New Look at Geometry”. This does not directly answer your question, but the man was a genius and you may learn something that interests you. See Internet Archive.

Comment: Nothing philosophical here : [Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry) is the discipline whose object of study is *space*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Actually there is a great deal of philosophical controversy over that question, from ancient times and especially since non-Euclidean geometries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Vincenzo De Risi](https://books.google.com/books?id=1m11BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false), referenced by [Wikipedia's article on Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry), geometry today is related to space as follows: (page 1)

> Today the definition of geometry as the *science of space* is generally accepted by both epistemologists and mathematicians.

To use the suggested form of relationship, this would mean that "space and geometry are related by science". However, "geometry as the science of space" may make more sense. One could also say that "space is the object of geometry".

This view has an historical origin around the 17th century. De Risi notes the difference between classical geometry and modern geometry as follows:

> While the primary aim of classical geometry was the calculation of lengths, areas and volumes of given figures, in a geometry of space the notion of position, incidence or direction may play a central role.

With the classical position geometry would not have been related as easily to space.

---

Vincenzo De Risi. Mathematizing Space: The Objects of Geometry from Antiquity to the Early Modern Age. (2015) Birkhauser. Retrieve on September 25, 2019 from https://books.google.com/books?id=1m11BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I would have thought general relativity was the science of space...

Comment: @Speakpigeon Think of Minkowski's geometrical formulation (mathematization) of Einstein's general theory as the geometry of space (and now also time) as what De Risi is referring to.

Comment: Sure, but it would have been the same job for Minkowski had he formalised any other theory. He only observed Einstein's theory, so to speak. It's maths, not anything like empirical science, as your piece seems to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming space is an aspect of the material world, the geometry of space may be thought of as the theoretical formal expression or model of the properties we believe are those of space on the basis of empirical evidence.

Both necessity and possibility are relevant here but only as modalities of our representation of space. We think of space as having degrees of freedom, whereby what we think of as physical objects can potentially move in different directions or rotate around different axes.

Whether anything at all of our formal model of space corresponds to the reality of space is anybody's guess. So, it might be that our geometry of space is only a model of properties of our epistemological relation to space. No quite the same thing.

Geometry as a mathematical discipline is something else. First, it is a discipline, not anything like a theory, let alone a theoretical model of anything.   And then, as a discipline, it can host a number of theories, all broadly thought of as theories of mathematical geometry.

The distinction is significant. While Euclid most likely thought of his own geometry as a formal model of what people thought, broadly, as space, mathematicians today spread themselves over a wide spectrum of perspectives.

Some may still conceive of a theory of mathematical geometry as a model of the abstract properties of space, while at the other end of the spectrum others may conceive of mathematical geometry as an exploration of the formal properties not of space but of the theories of geometry themselves, theories thought of as not necessarily of space itself but *related* somehow to the original notion of space, with perhaps sometimes the belief that only this can get you beyond the probably misleading empirical appearance of space to the ultimate reality of it.

As such, it is more a metaphysics than a science of space, although always with the potential to morph into a science as soon as new empirical evidence comes in to confirm the theory.